# How to access global state in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am just curious if there is a way to access the global state in redux from my component without using `mapStateToProps`.

Thanks.

Comment: Technically, you can use store.subscribe for redux inside useEffect and use it without react-redux https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener Not sure if there is any practical sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

- mapDispatchToProps
- mergeProps (this one will give you what you want)
- options

in the [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect) function provided by react-redux

Comment: He said that he doesn't want to use mapDispatchToProps

Comment: yes, these are just other options other than mapStateToProps

Answer (score 4):

you can make use of the useSelector hook from the react-redux library to access the store without mapping it to your props.